# How to use AWS Cognito as Identity Provider?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, saml

I want to use AWS Cognito as an IdP. My app named "XYZ" has a login screen, which takes user credentials and hits cognito to verify the user's identity using SAML based implementation. I do have a SAML meta data file for AWS Cognito as a service provider but i need the SAML based metadata file for AWS Cognito as an identity provider. Can i even use SAML implementation in this case or do i have to use OIDC?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512540/saml-idp-aws-cognito-iam-as-an-identity-provider

Answer (score 0):

Create an identity pool using federated auth through the SAML provider.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/saml-identity-provider.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

AWS Cognito does not support SAML IDP, and is just an OIDC IDP, you can use [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) as a middle layer between cognito and the SP.

the SAML XML metadata file will be generated by Auth0 (under Application/Addons/Usage/Identity Provider Metadata).