# SSO Login to AWS Connect using Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, saml, amazon-connect

My site has login through AWS Cognito Identity. And then user login to AWS Connect in pop-up window. I need combine it to one login. Is it possible to make it without external services, using AWS only?
AWS Connect can use SAML login, but it seems Cognito can't be SAML IdP itself?

Comment: Not directly, have a look in the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512540/saml-idp-aws-cognito-iam-as-an-identity-provider