SP Initiated SAML SSO for cognito
I have a user pool configured in cognito with some users. I need to login to a service using these user accounts. The service supports SAML SSO and asks for SSO URL, SAML Entity ID and SAML Certificate file. I am new to setting up SSO. I have tried reading up on SAML and SSO. Based on my understanding I felt what I need to setup is, an SP initiated SAML SSO where Cognito will be the IdP. Is this understanding correct?
Also in cognito where do I go to get my SSO URL and SAML certificate to provide to my service? Most of the tutorials I see uses OIDC which I believe the service I am working with does not support. Also with SAML I see a lot of content on using Auth0 or Okta but not Cognito.

Still this appears to be the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512540/saml-idp-aws-cognito-iam-as-an-identity-provider?rq=4
